# Is the use of "both" is correct in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, punctuation

Requesting someone's help,

In recent times, the vast advancement in digital technology has led to dramatic improvements in both how people interact with each other and maintain and build relationships.

I searched through google to find use of both in similar sentences, but didn't find anything. I doubt if the use of "both" and use of "how" just after "both" is correct in this way. Also, Is there any punctuation required in this case. Source: trying to write about what digital technology has improved in communication and connections between people.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you try to look up that on a dictionary, such as Cambridge Dictionary, Oxford Dictionary?

Comment: @WXJ96163 - thanks for your response, I saw many examples of "both" in a sentence on the Cambridge Dictionary. Unfortunately didn't come across something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence parts after "both" lack parallelism, which they should have to be combined under the word "both". A suggested correction:
"... in both how people interact with each other and how they maintain and build relationships."
A simpler correction would be just to drop the word "both" from the sentence, leaving "how people interact with each other and maintain and build relationships."

Comment: Thank you, your response is very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I would omit 'both' since that word refers to 2 of something and in your version people are interacting, maintaining and building.